# Solr, adding a record via JSON with a multi-value field and boosted values

Tags: solr

I'm pretty new to Solr, I'm trying to add a multi-value field with boost values defined for each value, all defined via JSON. In other words, I'd like this to work:

```
[{ "id": "ID1000",
  "tag": [ 
    { "boost": 1, "value": "A test value" }, 
    { "boost": 2, "value": "A boosted value" } ]
}]
```

I know how to do that in XML (multiple `<field name = 'tag' boost = '...'>`), but the JSON code above doesn't work, the server says "Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START". Has Solr a limit/bug?

PS: I fixed the originally-missing ']' and that's not the problem.

EDIT: It seems the way to go should be payloads (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Payloads), but I couldn't make them to work on Solr (followed this: http://sujitpal.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/payloads-with-solr.html). Leaving the question open to see if someone can further help.

Answer (score 4):

Found the following sentence in the from the [Solr Relevancy FAQ - Query Elevation Component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Query_Elevation_Component) section

> An Index-time boost on a value of a multiValued field applies to all values for that field.

I do not think adding an individual boost to each value in the multivalued field is going to work. I know that the Xml will allow it, but I would guess that it may only apply the boost value from the last value applied to the field.

So based on that I would change the Json to the following and see if that works.

```
[
    {
        "id": "ID1000",
        "tag": {
           "boost": 2, 
           "value": [ "A test value", "A boosted value"]
         }
    }
]
```

Comment: This is a very clear explanation and indeed your version is working, thanks a lot.

However I wonder how I can cover my use case: I have documents that have tags and tag weights attached, where the weight is a measure of how significant that tag is for the document. I want to search docs over tags and score something like: (article1, sport(3), society(2), gossip(1)) differently, depending on the query keywords.

Is it possible to deal with such a case and how?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON seems to be invalid missing a closing `]`

```
[
    {
        "id": "ID1000",
        "tag": [
            {
                "boost": 1,
                "value": "A test value"
            },
            {
                "boost": 2,
                "value": "A boosted value"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem, originally I had good JSON (validated via http://jsonlint.com/), just lost the bracket during reformatting here.

Comment: did you try removing the outside [] completely ?

Answer (score 0):

You hit an edge case. You can have the boosts on single values and you can have an array of values. But not one inside another (from [my reading of Solr 4.1 source code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_1/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/loader/JsonLoader.java#L436))

That might be something to [create as an enhancement request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR).

If you are generating that JSON by hand, you can try:

```
"tag": { "boost": 1, "value": "A test value" }, 
"tag": { "boost": 2, "value": "A boosted value" }
```

I believe Sols will merge the values then. But if you are generating it via a framework, it will most likely disallow or override multiple object property names (*tag* here).

Comment: No that won't work. It seems someone else hase already noticed this problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2499 but not fixed yet... :-(

Comment: Looks like related but separate issue. It is saying that even if you manage to boost the values, it will not quite have the expected effect. You are saying that you can't even get the boosts in with JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with boosting.
I get the same error with a very simple json doc.
No luck solving it.
see [Solr errors when trying to parse a collection: Error parsing JSON field value. Unexp ected OBJECT_START](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909107/solr-errors-when-trying-to-parse-a-collection-error-parsing-json-field-value-u)

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error message. Actually the error message was misplaced. The underlying real error was the two of the required fields as per schema.xml in solr configuration were missing in the json payload.

An error message of the kind "required parameters are missing in the document" would have been more helpful here. You might want to check if some required fields are missing in the json payload.